Flutter Unit Test With Localization
I have a utility class that relies on the context in order to translate the output.
Something along the lines of :
static String doSomeLogicAndTranslate(String firstArg, BuildContext context) {
    //...
    return AppLocalizations.of(context)!.someKey;
}

Now, I want to be able to write some unit tests for this class, but since the second argument is the context, I'm having a hard time doing so.
What I have tried so far:

Mocking a BuildContext with Mockito (as described here) and passing that as the second argument --> Doesn't work as inside the localizations.dart file it returns null here
  static T? of<T>(BuildContext context, Type type) {
      final _LocalizationsScope? scope = context.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<_LocalizationsScope>();  /// Scope is null here
      return scope?.localizationsState.resourcesFor<T?>(type);
  }



I have tried looking around for any other solutions for this, but have not found anything substantial. This seems like it should be pretty straight forward, but it isn't.

My first suggestion would be to remove the dependency on BuildContext altogether by passing AppLocalizations directly to your function:
static String doSomeLogicAndTranslate(String firstArg, AppLocalizations loc) {
    //...
    return loc.someKey;
}

test('AppLocalizations test', () {
  final loc = lookupAppLocalizations(const Locale('en'));
  final output = doSomeLogicAndTranslate('some arg', loc);
  // Calls to expect or whatever here
});

If that's not possible for some reason, you can use testWidgets to set up a minimal widget tree and retrieve a valid build context for the rest of your test from there:
testWidgets('AppLocalizations test', (tester) async {
  await tester.pumpWidget(
    Localizations(
      locale: const Locale('en'), // Or whichever locale you prefer to test with
      delegates: AppLocalizations.localizationsDelegates,
      child: Container(),
    ),
  );
  final BuildContext context = tester.element(find.byType(Container));
  final output = doSomeLogicAndTranslate('some arg', context);
  // Calls to expect or whatever here
});


Passing in an argument of AppLocalizations is tantamount to passing context, since to create the AppLocalizations instance, you need a context.

Using testWidgets does overcome the problem since there is an inherited widget to depend on, but it seems like overkill to do this just to use translations in a unit test.

You do not need a BuildContext to instantiate AppLocalizations, it's just that you should access it through context in the running application. I just updated the code to show one way to instantiate AppLocalizations in a normal unit test. It's also possible to instantiate the specific implementation directly or fake/mock the class.
